# Title display in agendaWeek view differs based on fullcalendar js file loaded

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

In the agendaWeek view the emdash that displays between the days in the calendar title displays differently based on which fullcalendar.js I load.  For example, if I load the full calendar.js file it works as it should:

Feb 8 — 14, 2015

using this script tag:

```
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.js'></script>
```

When I try to save bandwidth by loading the minified version as fullcalendar.min.js I get the following output:

Feb 8 â€” 14, 2015

Using the script tag:

```
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

My server is outputting the Content-Type charset as UTF-8, and I use the meta tag http-equiv to set it as well.  Why would a minified version of full calendar not properly display the emdash while the full version does?

As a follow-up, I installed fullcalendar locally using the download and the fullcalendar.min.js file and it works correctly.  So that led me to believe the file on CDNJS might be different but running a diff return that the files match exactly.  What could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe their minification process is foo-baring it

Answer (score 24):

You will need to edit the minified version in the titleRangeSeparator section.
Do Ctrl+F and search titleRangeSeparator and change `â€”` to `\u2014`.

But if you don't want to download the file to edit you can always set the option `titleRangeSeparator` on initialization.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there any others way? because I don't want to do changes in minified CSS.

Comment: Yes, as I've mentioned on my answer you can set the option 'titleRangeSeparator' on initialization to anything you want without changing the CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with fullcalendar week view. The problem here may not be of encoding but a missing "lang-all.js" along with the "lang" folder that comes with the package. Please go through all the js files and compare with the default package. In my case this was the problem and by including these missing files the issue was resolved.

Hope this would be helpful.