# Title on FullCalendar month view not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

Please check out the web page I am making at https://preview.c9.io/tomheaps/enharmonic/Website/enharmonic_calendar.html?_c9_id=livepreview2&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io which has an embedded google calendar, styled using the jquery plugin FullCalendar.

As you will see, when you click on month view, the title is not displaying properly with some strange characters between the two dates and shows '1st â€” 7th June 2015' instead of '1st - 7th June 2015' for example.

I am not sure if this is happening because I am using Open Sans as the font for this title and it doesn't contain the glyph that is inserted automatically by the javascript?

Can anyone think of a workaround for this that allows me to still use Open Sans?

Comment: Apologies, I meant to say WEEK view, not month view!!

Comment: I am not sure if this would help, but try adding the proper meta tag for character encoding and see if it translate those characters to the correct symbol. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp)

Comment: It is an encoding problem that is listed here: [UTF-8 Encoding Debugging Chart](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html).

Comment: you are absolutely right, that is the character that should be displayed. Any idea how I can rectify this on my page as I don't understand how to use the advice on the page you linked to which states 'Look for references to ISO-8859-1 and replace them with "Windows-1252" (or CP1252, or the correct character encoding name for the library or platform you are using.)'

Comment: Adding the meta tag might not fix the problem. It could be caused by the application you use to editor your pages.  This happens when a page is saved with one encoding type and displayed in another type.  Check your page editor for an option to save as UTF-8 ... and not some other format like Windows 1252.

Comment: using cloud9 which only supports UTF-8 encoding for files!

Comment: I see you added the meta tag to the page and that it works now.  So thanks for giving Thiago Avelino credit.

Comment: Problel solved here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491639/title-display-in-agendaweek-view-differs-based-on-fullcalendar-js-file-loaded

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tom, make sure that you are serving your HTML as UTF-8:
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

Include the tag below right after the html tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: tried this but doesn't make any difference, still seeing 'â€”' instead of '-'

Comment: Tested on Firefox/IE it showed the correct "—" character. Apparently it's a chrome issue.

Comment: Roberto - are you using a mac or windows computer?

Comment: Has just started working in chrome for some reason, possibly browser cleared its cache and the meta tag is now taking effect. Thanks guys.

Comment: I am using a JSP, so I had to also change the encoding in the JSP header: `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue I was seeing â instead of —. It is a codification problem.

I solved it easily:

**Observation:**

- In fullcalendar v.3.9.0, the **titleRangeSeparator** from the
  fullcalendar.js is '**\u2013**' which is correct.
- However, fullcalendar.min.js the **titleRangeSeparator** is **—**.

**Solution:**

- I changed manually the value of **titleRangeSeparator** from the file
  fullcalendar.min.js from'**-**' to '**\u2013**' --> problem fixed.

Comment: thank you very much, you saved my life, in my opinion this is the correct answer and should be accepted

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, while developing all was fine, when deployed got this problem.

As @PolFernandez [pointed out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697409/title-on-fullcalendar-month-view-not-displaying-properly/50375476#50375476) (thank you man) , the problem is that minified version of fullcalendar library had different notation for separator.

If you don't want to modify original fullcalendar.min.js you can simply set the separator in calendar initialization:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    views: {
        month: { columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd', displayEventEnd: true, eventLimit: 3 },
        week: { columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd DD', titleRangeSeparator: ' \u2013 ' },
        day: { columnHeaderFormat: 'dddd' },
    },
});
```